# MD5 Checksum problem in java

Tags: java, md5

I am receiving byte array data from in Big Endian format with checksum. I have created the checkcksum using following code.

```
public static byte[] createChecksum(byte buffer[], int len){ 
     MessageDigest complete = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
     complete.update(buffer,0,len);
     return complete.digest();
}
```

While checking the checksum with data it is not matching. I have checked the data. data is not corrupted or wrong. I also found that only one byte in middle is not matching between two checksum.

Comment: to what are you comparing the md5 checksum?

Comment: The checksum comes with the data.

Comment: I suspect the checksums are not being calculated exactly the same way.  BTW: bytes are always bytes, there is no endianness. Is it possible you are reading the checksum incorrectly?

Comment: md5sum usually come supplied in hex format. I'd like to see the code that reads in or prints out that string. It would be extremely unlikely to just get an md5sum with one byte difference if there is some off-by-one bug or the like somewhere.

Comment: Are you sure that you are excluding the hash itself from the checksum calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Your method looks correct.

Maybe you get an undesired result because you get a byte array and you need to convert to HEX later? Can you write an example of what file you are hashing and the result (you get and you expect)?

Have you checked that the input byte array has the correct encoding and is exactly what it should be? Be aware of trailing lines, spaces and so on.

Answer (score 0):

possible reasons:

- you did not read the entire content into the buffer
- you supplied wrong 'len' parameter

however reading the following

> > I also found that only one byte in middle is not matching between two checksum.

makes me believe there is an error in the function checking the resulting md5 (or the one that sends/receives it). 
Well, for md5 alike hashfunctions that is exceptionally impossible (only 1 byte difference) and if it reoccurring it's definitely a mistake into snd/rcv and/or comparing the result code.

Side note: Big/Little Endian makes sense only if when representing 'primitives' that take more than a single byte.

Comment: I have checked with the len i am providing. I also chck with data array I am providing to create checksum.

Comment: The checksum I got is 3fce3c93fd03f43f783efee11b6e37b   The generated Checksum is 3fce3c93fd09d43f783efee11b6e37b

Comment: can you post the code that receives the data; it's just not possible to generate so similar hash results. Also, if you can add the data, itself, leading to those results